# Normal user touching a file in /var/run failed

Tags: linux

I have a program called ***HelloWorld*** belonging to user ***test***

***HelloWorld*** will create a file ***HelloWorld.pid*** in ***/var/run*** to keep single instance.
I using following command to try to make ***test*** can access ***/var/run***

```
usermod -a -G root test
```

However, when I run it, falied

could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some linux systems store per-user runtime files in `/var/run/user/UID/`.

In this case you can create your pid file in `/var/run/user/$(id -u test)/HelloWorld.pid`.

---

Alternatively just use `/tmp`.

You may want to use the user's name as a prefix to the pid filename to avoid collision with other users, for instance `/tmp/test-HelloWorld.pid`.

Comment: I have only a **root** in **/var/run/user/** in my system. I do have a user called **test**.

Comment: @mac.ma see alternative in answer.

Answer (score 1):

What are the permissions on `/var/run`? On my system, `/var/run` is `rwxr-xr-x`, which means only the **user** `root` can write to it. The permissions do not allow write access by members of the `root` group.

The normal way of handling this is by creating a subdirectory of `/var/run` that is owned by the user under which you'll be running your service.  E.g.,

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/helloworld
sudo chown myusername /var/run/helloworld
```

Note that `/var/run` is often an ephemeral filesystem that disappears when your system reboots. If you would like your target directory to be created automatically when the system boots you can do that using the systemd [tmpfiles](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html#) service.

Comment: what i want is an ephemeral file, so it can keep my program can only run once. And when system shutdown, this file will deleted automatically, so next time i reboot, i can run my program again

Comment: ...and that is exactly what I have described. Because `/var/run` is an ephemeral filesystem, any files created on it disappear when your system reboots. I believe this answer is exactly what you want.